# Validating Xcode archive without being the final deployer

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

We are developing an iOS application for a customer who manages his apps under his own name in iTunes Connect.
I was wondering if there was a feasible way to validate an ipa when you are not the final instance which will actually upload the bundle to the App Store. A common scenario is that you deploy an application bundle to a customer so that he will be the one who manages the app in iTunes Connect, but you still want to make sure that everything checks out once the app is in your customers hands.

To be clear: we don't have access to our customers iTunes Connect but we archive the application with their distribution profile.

The idea which came to mind is to create a mock application in our own iTunes Connect without the intention to actually release the application. One could expand on this and actually do a pre-review of the app to make sure the app will not cause unpleasant surprises after we sent the archive to or customer. Will Apple throw any rocks in this path? I could imagine that they won't be happy that developers will let review the same app version twice...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Why would giving a customer a bundle allow them to manage it on the app store ? What do you mean validate an xCode archive ? Really unclear question.

Comment: It is our customers policy to manage all applications made in their name, which is very understandable. It just makes the deployment of the app more complicated. Validating an Xcode archive is possible from the organizer. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-archives_organizer/articles/validating_apps.html

Answer (score 1):

You ask about whether the final Xcode archive could be tested. Yes, it can be tested. You should ask your customer to send you a copy of the submitted application, as it appears in the Xcode organizer). They would have to resign the bundle with **THEIR** AdHoc profile that should contain YOUR device, and send the IPA to you. You would then be able to check the final submitted app.

For the second part of your question, which is most interesting: It would be great to release the app in your account and then let the customer release it again. There are two problems: if the reviewer is the same, then your customer's app may be rejected. And: if the reviewer is not the same, it could pass validation with the first reviewer and fail with the second one.